# Joomla Admin Page Index.php code missing

Tags: php, joomla, admin

I encountered a weird problem today, I found that my joomla Website administrator page got hacked by hackers and deleted all the code. I hosted my site on godaddy and they charge around 150$ for backing up single page. I want to take some suggestions from experts on stackoverflow if there will be any other option to get the code back. I am on windows hosting on godaddy.

Comment: This might help: [Advice on what to do after being hacked?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/advice-on-what-to-do-after-being-hacked)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the PHP file for your Joomla, you can just download a copy from joomla.org, unzip and upload it to your server, overwriting existing files.
The content of your site is all stored withing the database. The only special file on your server is the configuration.php file which holds things like database connection informations.
Also when uploading make sure to not upload the "installation" folder from the zipfile. This is only needed during installation and is deleted afterwards. Joomla will show an error message if the folder is found.

However if you really got hacked, then it's most likely that they also uploaded additional scriptfiles hidden somewhere. Finding and deleting those is the more difficult part.